# [Survey]: Should we burninate this tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [survey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survey)-tag seems very odd. It has no tag wiki and I couldn't find a framework named "survey". Of course, there are some survey frameworks for programming languages like [LimeSurvey](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey), but they have their own tag.

There are 500 questions tagged with survey. **It simply doesn't make sense as a tag**.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It describes the content, but very broadly. It would be better to tag the specific framework.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Programming surveys is on-topic for SO, but surveys per se are clearly off topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

I don't think a question would benefit from this tag.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Surveys could be anything. It generally means some kind of "form" where users enter some data and in the end you display the results. But this is **very, very broad**.

Comment: surely the survey will survive this subversion ;)

Comment: Suggested title: [survey] says burninate this tag ([it's a meme](http://memecrunch.com/meme/ADLM8/survey-says/image.jpg))

Comment: It looks like R has a survey package and Odoo has a survey module, but most of the questions seem like a scattershot of people trying to create surveys. Those two should probably have specific tags, since the general one is too ambiguous.

Comment: I actually thought this was a survey

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson: It is, but there's only one page, Question 1 has nothing but a freeform textbox to answer in, and there aren't any other questions.

Comment: Of course we know this is a [survey], the [meta-tag:discussion] tag implies it, no need to title your post with "[Survey]: ..." :p

Comment: I think the tag is just fine, if it's a question *about* (programming) surveys, not used as a meta tag describing a question formulated as a survey (which should be closed as opinion-based anyway).